# Configuring Mame

Tags: mame

I've installed Mame on Ubuntu 16.04, so far so good, but now wish to add my ROMS.
I want to edit the mame.ini file but all I get is "permission denied" despite being an administrator (the only account), which seems to be a 'feature' of Ubuntu!!
I'd rather not be messing about with command lines, especially as I can open and edit in GUI.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need `root` permissions to edit the file,. you will need to open it from a terminal but you can use a GUI editor to edit it.

First way to do this (and likely best for you) is to open the file manger as `root` with

```
gksu nautilus
```

and browse to the file you want to edit.

Alternatively, open the text editor and file directly

```
gksu gedit /path/to/the/file
```

Where `/path/to/the/file` is the location of the file you wish to edit.

Comment: Just going round in circles! "The program 'gksu' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install gksu"

Comment: Do what it says, run `sudo apt-get install gksu`